# js external is not working in head tag of html

Tags: javascript, html

My js external file is not working in a head tag, however, it's working on calling at the end of code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> java Script</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="myjavascript.js"> </script>    
</head>
```

Comment: So your script probably tries to access something that isn't there when it loads in the head, wonder what that could be ?

Comment: its working by making async.

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: <script async src="myjavascript.js"> </script> by this way it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the browser can render a page it has to build the DOM tree by parsing the HTML markup. During this process, whenever the parser encounters a script it has to stop and execute it before it can continue parsing the HTML. If your script tries to access an element in the `<body>` of your file, it will fail because that part of the DOM is not loaded as yet.

Place your script before the end `<body>` tag.

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS

Comment: yes it's working at the end of body tag but how will it be work in head tag?

Comment: its working by making async. like    <script async src="myjavascript.js"> </script>

Comment: @hanif You can also use the `defer` attribute `<script defer src="myjavascript.js">`